# Ionic: How to change the Icon on iOS when user is in the "switch apps screen"

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently a bit confused about how to change the icon in the iOS "switch apps screen".
I've already changed all the icons for cordova resources, but it sill won't change, check the following screenshot. [iOS icon missing on "Switch apps screen"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlaQ9.png)

All other icons are working...
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: please check this you will come to know how to control these icon in your application

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources

Comment: @TaylorRahul I have done that already (mentioned in the original post aswell), the screenshot shows that the one single icon still won't work even I have used cordova resources and double-checked all of the resources after building...

Comment: what size of icon and splash you have used. can you please let me know

Comment: Nevermind, it already worked. The issue was that I've changed the icon in a previous version and I had to uninstall the app, restart my iPhone and install it again for the icon to update.

Answer (score 0):

As the original poster said, after making sure you updated all the icon resources sizes, uninstall the app and restart the phone, then re-install the app. You should see the correct icon when switching apps now. It seems the OS is caching this icon and a phone restart is needed to clear this cache.